# How to create a IntellijIDEA code template specific to some directory

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a maven project with default structure:

```
src/main/java
src/test/java
```

I want to create a template for tests, because they have very similar structure. I create tests with right-click on `src/test/java` -> new -> Java class. My question is how do I create a test template for new classes added to `src/test/java` only? I don't need this template to be triggered when adding new classes to `src/main/java`.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for "File and Code Templates" in Preferences. In the "Code" tab you can find all templates and can adjust them (i.e. "JUnit5 Test Class").

Comment: yeah, but when I add a new Java class, IDE doesn't yet know that it will be a Junit file,so the template is never triggered

Comment: When having the class open you want to write a test for, go to Code/Generate (cmd-N in MacOS), choose "Test..." in the popup.